# Valgrind and time give opposite results

Tags: optimization, fortran, valgrind, callgrind

I have some (Fortran) code which accumulates data into an array, essentially doing this:

```
complex,dimension(4000)::a,b
complex :: c
[...]
a=0.
do i=1,20000
    b=foo(...)
    c=bar(...)
    a=a+b*c
end do
```

Using callgrind, I learn that most of my program's effort is in executing the line

```
a=a+b*c
```

so I'm interested in whether I can do anything to accelerate this. As a starting point, I have tried using the BLAS libraries optimized for my system, and replacing this line with

```
call caxpy(4000,c,b,1,a,1)
```

Callgrind reports this reduces the 'Ir count' for the entire program by about 40%. However, the execution time as measured by 'time' increases, by around 20%.

I expected that run time should be roughly proportional to the number of instructions executed, and so the two measures ought to give comparable results (time reports 99% CPU usage). What am I missing here?

Comment: What compiler and options (-O3, eg) are you using?

Comment: Also, which BLAS implementation? And are your a,b and c arrays or scalars then? More clear piece of code would be preferable. Especially a compilable one which we could try. How expensive are `foo` and `bar`? Try look for the overhead of calling `caxpy` and try to increase the array size.

Comment: @Ross - This was with 'gfortran -O5 -g'.

Comment: @VladimirF - I'm using the BLAS packaged within the AMD Core Math Library. As declared, a and b are arrays; c is scalar. Unfortunately my real code is several thousand lines long, so posting it here is impossible. foo() essentially loads data from disk; bar() is some cheap arithmetic. I will look into the caxpy overhead - but I'm still puzzled by why this would be reported by time as user (not system) costs, yet not be reflected in callgrind's instruction count.

Comment: Not only the instruction count counts, don't forget memory accesses (stack modifications for the subroutine call) and the CPU pipeline inefficiencies when jumping far.